# Installed Gapps, but Google Play services is not there

Tags: google-play-services

So I finally found a way to install CWM in my Lava Iris 430 which runs on ICS 4.0.4 and installed Gapps (gapps-ics-20120429-signed version). It was successfully installed, but it missed Google Play Services. What should I do?

Comment: This happens with Copperhead OS too : If you install gapps, then it simply does not appear when you boot.  It can be avoided but only with some rather more serious effort.  I asked a more specific question about why it happens here :   https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179447/10506

Answer (score -1):

Open the Play Store and Google Play Services will download automatically.