# Signal, WhatsApp, etc. without Gapps on Copperhead

Tags: security, whatsapp-messenger, google-play-services

There is seemingly no way to install gapps on Copperhead OS anymore, as indicated by the Copperhead OS bugtracker.  Yet, Mike Perry does it by [installing Copperhead piecemeal](https://github.com/mikeperry-tor/mission-improbable/blob/master/install-copperhead.sh#L39-L42).  What is going on here?  What in Copperhead OS's unified install breaks gapps?  Is it just the `android-info.txt` file in the image zip?

As an aside, I only wanted to install Google Play Services because it sounded like Signal, WhatsApp, and maybe Wire might not receive messages in the background without gapps pico installed.  Signal warns about this, and asks to burn oodls of battery to fix it, but I do not know if this really matters.  I do know microG cannot be used to fix it currently because the way microG spoofs Google Play Services breaks security throughout the phone.

Comment: Is your question really "What is going on here?" or would you like to be more specific? What kind of answer are you hoping for?

Comment: What do you mean when you say " I do know microG cannot be used to fix it currently because the way microG spoofs Google Play Services breaks security throughout the phone". What security risks are you talking about?

Comment: I elaborated that what I want to understand is why you cannot simply install gapps on copperhead when seemingly all the same pieces work.

Comment: Also,  it's noted that microG enabling key spoofing creates a security vulnerability in both the copperhead bugtracker and the mission improbable future work section, presumably if an adversary can get you to install any app then that app can pretend to be any other app and do bad things.  The fix might be to somehow restrict the key spoofing to only microG spoofing only google play services, but I know zero about what that entails.

Comment: As an aside, it appears Signal responds to the lack of Google Play Services by burning slightly more battery, while WhatsApp only checks when you wake it, so you kinda only get messages when using WhatsApp.